# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException when loading JSON file

Tags: json, apache-spark

I've got a large datastore of JSON objects that I'm trying to load into Spark in a dataframe, but I'm receiving an AnalysisException when trying to do any processing on the data.  There are several differently formatted JSON objects in the input data.  Some of them have the same fields in different orders and/or levels of the JSON.

I've loaded the JSON in with the following code.

```
    val messagesDF = spark.read.json("data/test")
```

But once I try to perform any operations on the data I receive the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'SGLN' is ambiguous, could be: SGLN#1099, SGLN#1204.;
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext.showDF(ZeppelinContext.java:235)
  ... 48 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'SGLN' is ambiguous, could be: SGLN#1099, SGLN#1204.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:129)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:96)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:129)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileSourceStrategy$.apply(FileSourceStrategy.scala:83)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at 

org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2814)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2127)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2342)
      ... 52 more
```

Everything I've been able to find on this error is from joining different dataframes which is certainly similar to what I'm trying to do, but I can't go in and refactor the dataframe to provide unique ids.

Comment: can you paste sample input json (data/test)?

Comment: there are two `SGLN` keys in your json data as the error is suggesting `'SGLN' is ambiguous, could be: SGLN#1099, SGLN#1204` so you will have to find a mechanism to replace one of them